# frontend не работает flex justify

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Не работает css свойство `justify-content`

Вот код короче:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.content {
    flex:1;
    margin-bottom: 2vh;
}
.wrap-content-footer {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 5vh - 3vh); /* -headerHeight-headerMarginBottom*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.header-link {
    flex:1;
}
header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 9vh;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background: rgb(179, 179, 179);
}
footer {
    min-height: 3vh;
}
```

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{{Title}}</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header-link"><a href="{% url 'index:index' %}">Главная</a></div>
        <div class="header-link"><a href="{% url 'index:index' %}">Главная</a></div>
    </header>

    <div class="wrap-content-footer">
        <div class="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>

        <footer>
            Статус: {{statusbar}}
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ну так `space-between` распределяет равномерно "элементы". А у тебя в хедере он только один. Попробуй `flex-star`, `flex-end` или `center`.

Comment: center тоже не работает... Хотя, я поспал, так что код щас по-другому будет работать, ща проверю. UPD: не работает(

Comment: А если для div убрать flex: 1?

Comment: Что-то меняется, но пожалуй в худшую сторону, сами то проверяли?

Comment: Да. "Главная" по центру стала с justify content : center;

Comment: Если добавить еще один элемент, он встанет впритык, с тем...

Comment: Я не понимаю чего ты хочешь именно добиться от своего кода. Скажи мне и я может быть помогу.

Comment: чтобы они держали одинаковое расстояние друг от друга, `text-algin: center;` работает, но он вроде с картинками не работает, то есть если я захочу место текста поставить картинку у меня не получится, поэтому нужно `justify-content:center` НО ОН НЕ РАБОТАЕТ

Comment: Если ты применяешь text-algin: center для div'а в котором лежит картинка то картинка будет выравниваться. Но я все равно не понял кто эти "Они", которые должны держать одинаковое расстояние друг от друга, когда у  тебя в хедере всего "ОДИН" элемент. В общем, мой совет добавь border для всех элементов, может быть так ты лучше поймешь как и чем управлять,чтобы добиться нужного результата. Вот так, например :
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none; 
border: 1px solid black;
}

Comment: Это пока что ОДИН элемент, что тут не понятного... Допустим, окей, text-algin работает, но вопрос остался. Почему justify-content не работает?

Comment: Потому что пока у тебя один элемент, для которого ты задал flex:1; он  у тебя всю ширину блока занимает.  соответственно позиционирование для него будет безразлично, поэтому и не работает. Добавь бордеры для всех элементов как я посоветовал выше и ты сам все увидишь.

Comment: так он не один... Я для всего КЛАССА задал. Или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: В твоем коде он один с таким классом. Я так понимаю там не одна ссылка будет. Поэтому сначала делают разметку полностью, а только потом стилизуют. А ты начал стилизовать только с одним элементом. Разметь все что будет в хедере, а только потом занимайся стилизацией.

Comment: Повнимательнее прочитайте еще раз мой код, я уже давно изменил на 2 Элемента....